# Search files through case sensitive extension on command line

Tags: windows, search, command-line, case-sensitive, file-extension

Search files through case sensitive extension on the Windows command line. I want the search a list of jpg files in my directory where some files has extension xxx.jpg and some yyy.JPG .

Here I want the list of all files who has extension yyy.JPG

Any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? If so, than this is not a DOS question.

Comment: Yes @dbenham it is a DOS question i think. :) bcoz I want to Search list of files through case sensitive extension on Windows command prompt (its MS-DOS)

Comment: The Windows command line has nothing to do with "DOS" or "MS-DOS". It's a command line, not an operating system.

Answer (score 2):

dir *.jpg|findstr /e /L ".JPG"

shoud deliver that list; only when the end of the lines literally match the string will `findstr` allow the line through.

Answer (score 0):

command.com doesn't care about case, but the DOS API does pay attention.  So, writing a simple DOS program to search the files will allow you to match what you want.

You can also use most other programming languages (even BASIC!) to get a directory, and it will take you literally.  You could even get what you want by getting a directory listing from command.com and then piping it through the find command:

```
dir | find ".JPG"
```

Since you asked this on  Stackoverflow (programmer's site) it's assumed you want to write a program.  If not, youll want to try superuser.com instead.

Comment: Thank you gbarry for your suggestions. :)